# Kafka: deleting messages from topics with retention "compact"

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to implement a minimal working example on compacted topics in Kafka with Java. I got the compaction working well, but cannot see deletes happening when I write messages with a key and a null value as described in the kafka documentation.

Version of library used: kafka-clients-0.10.0.0.jar

Here is a gist of a Java class reproducing the behaviour:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f78184eaeec3ee82b15182aec24a432a

Furthermore, consulting the documentation, I used the following configuration on a topic level for compaction to kick in as quickly as possible:

```
min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.01
cleanup.policy=compact
segment.ms=100
delete.retention.ms=100
```

On the server.properties side, just to be sure:

```
log.retention.check.interval.ms=100
log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=100
log.cleaner.enable=true
log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio=0.01
```

When run, this class shows that compaction works - there is only ever one message with the same key on the topic. However, I still see the message with the "null" value, that should have been deleted in my opinion.

I can see the cleaner threads running, producing output like:
[2016-08-11 12:30:21,032] INFO Cleaner 0: Cleaning segment 15 in log compaction-test-0 (last modified Thu Aug 11 12:29:52 CEST 2016) into 0, retaining deletes. (kafka.log.LogCleaner)

Does anyone know why it's "retaining deletes"? Am I missing any relevant configuration option? Am I writing "null" in the correct way?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: After investigating helpful comments, I upgraded to 0.10.0.1 and found the following output in the cleaner log:

```
[2016-08-15 12:44:57,412] INFO Cleaner 0: Cleaning log compaction-test-0 (discarding tombstones prior to Mon Aug 15 12:44:40 CEST 2016)... (kafka.log.LogCleaner)
[2016-08-15 12:44:57,412] INFO Cleaner 0: Cleaning segment 0 in log compaction-test-0 (last modified Mon Aug 15 12:44:41 CEST 2016) into 0, retaining deletes. (kafka.log.LogCleaner)
[2016-08-15 12:44:57,412] INFO Cleaner 0: Cleaning segment 15 in log compaction-test-0 (last modified Mon Aug 15 12:44:41 CEST 2016) into 0, retaining deletes. (kafka.log.LogCleaner)
[2016-08-15 12:44:57,413] INFO Cleaner 0: Cleaning segment 16 in log compaction-test-0 (last modified Mon Aug 15 12:44:56 CEST 2016) into 0, retaining deletes. (kafka.log.LogCleaner)
```

As "retaining deletes" is set by 
    val retainDeletes = old.lastModified > deleteHorizonMs
and the last modification date of the segment in question always seems slightly later than the delete horizon, deleting doesn't happen in my minimal example.

Just wondering how to adjust settings or test to deal with this now...

Comment: Since it could be a bug, it will help if you share the specific version where you saw this behavior.

Comment: You see "retaining deletes" because technically it is not time to discard the segment according to the last modified time of the last clean segment and the value of delete.retention.ms

Comment: @GwenShapira of course, good point, editing question.

Comment: @LucianoAfranllie: I thought with setting delete.retention.ms to 100, cleaning should kick in almost immediately as compaction does. I wonder if I have forgotten a setting.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw the code.

val deleteHorizonMs =
      log.logSegments(0, cleanable.firstDirtyOffset).lastOption match {
        case None => 0L
        case Some(seg) => seg.lastModified - log.config.deleteRetentionMs
    }
...
val retainDeletes = old.lastModified > deleteHorizonMs

This could be related to the fact that if there is no dirty offset then deleteHorizonMs is set to 0, in that case retainDeletes will be true since old.lastModified is a unix timestamp in ms.

Comment: @LucianoAfranllie you pointed me into a good direction, see the last update to my question...

Comment: @Jannixx, In your logs "Mon Aug 15 12:44:40 CEST 2016" is the value of deleteHorizonMs and for each segment last modified date is the value of old.lastModified. So, in your case it makes sense that Kafka retains those segments since they were modified after the deleteHorizon. So, the question that remains is: why the last clean segment is not newer than segments to be cleaned? Will do some tests later and let you know what I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been fixed in 0.10.1. See this JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4015